# How to make my NSUserNotification stay displayed until dismissed?

Tags: macos, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I am presenting our users with a high priority notification via an NSUserNotification, and I want it to stay persistently up until dismissed (like the App Store and Calendar apps do). Is there a flag of some sort I can set to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Code-sign your app and add the key `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` in `Info.plist` with value `alert`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this on a per-notification basis? I have a couple other different notifications I do not want to be persistent.